# Time difference between extraction of encrypted and unencrypted data

Tags: python, django, postgresql, encryption, pgcrypto

Suppose I have two models

```
class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 60,blank= False,)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length = 60,blank=False)
    marks = models.IntegerField(default =0,blank=True)
    teacher = models.CharField(max_length = 60,blank=False)
```

and another model

```
class EncryptedStudent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 60)
    subject = pgcrypto.EncryptedCharField(blank=False)
    marks = pgcrypto.EncryptedIntegerField(default = 0,blank= True)
    teacher = pgcrypto.EncryptedCharField(blank=False)
```

Now I want to query on the database. Will there be any time difference? How to evaluate for any time difference?

I am using `pgcrypto` module . Here is the github [link](https://github.com/dcwatson/django-pgcrypto).

Comment: Will retrieving results and decrypting them be slower than retrieving results and __not__ decrypting them?

Comment: @iain-shelvington no if I retrieve data from **Student** model will it be faster or time will remain same compared to **EncryptedStudent**

Comment: Time it and see.

Comment: I have relatively small data now. It doesn't seem to have much effect now. But I wanted to know theoretically if there would be any difference.